# Evaluate ${\cos ^{ - 1}}\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} = $ for $x<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Question:
Let $x<0$ then $\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}=$

(1) $\pi-\cos^{-1}x$

(2) $-\sin^{-1}x$

(3) $\pi-\sin^{-1}x$

(4) $\sin^{-1}x$

My approach is as follow

Given  $x < 0,{\cos ^{ - 1}}\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} $

Let  $x = \sin \theta $, therefore ${\cos ^{ - 1}}\sqrt {1 - {{\sin }^2}\theta }  = {\cos ^{ - 1}}\sqrt {{{\cos }^2}\theta }  = {\cos ^{ - 1}}\left| {\cos \theta } \right| = \theta $

Hence  ${\cos ^{ - 1}}\sqrt {1 - {{\sin }^2}\theta }  = {\cos ^{ - 1}}\sqrt {{{\cos }^2}\theta }  = {\cos ^{ - 1}}\left| {\cos \theta } \right| = {\sin ^{ - 1}}x$

But as per the graph answer is $-\sin^{-1}x$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Your mistake arises from when you say $\cos^{-1}|\cos\theta|=\theta$.  This is true if $\cos\theta$ is positive, but not if $\cos\theta$ is negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x=\sin \theta <0$ and $\cos \theta = \sqrt{1-x^2} >0$, angle $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrant. Thus, $\cos^{-1} |\cos \theta|=-\theta$